# How to troubleshoot messages sent from local compter to Azure IOT Hub using WireShark?

Tags: c#, azure, mqtt, tls1.2, azure-iot-hub

I am sending messages from my `C#` application to `IOT Hub` using below code snippet.

```
    public async Task<MessageToTargetStatus> ForwardMessage(byte[] message)
    {
        var messageToSend = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message(message);            
        await iotHubClient.GetDeviceClient().SendEventAsync(messageToSend).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return MessageToTargetStatus.Success;
    }
```

Messages are successfully received at the `Azure IOT Hub`

Now I want to test my security of these messages and trying to verify these messages in WireShark.

I see many records in `WireShark`, but I am not able to figure out which is my messages sent to IOT Hub.

How can I do it? I am using `MQTT` at port 1833, running as `Windows Service'.

I have added filter as follow, but no luck

[image]

MQTT I might need to force the packets over a networkadapter, using localhost windows will use loopback instead of the network interface card. So how can I do it in WireShark?

**Updated question with Device Explorer tool screenshot**

When I send single message from `Device Explorer`, I see many communication records in `WireShark`. Which protocol I should be filtering?

[image]

**Connection string** - I am using `Mqtt_WebSocket_Only`

```
  _hubClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(IotHubConnectionString, TransportType.Mqtt_WebSocket_Only);
```

Comment: Try ip.dst == your IOT Hub IP.

Comment: Tried but it's not capturing. strange

Comment: MQTT is always going to be TCP not UDP

Comment: @codetoshare Have you tried the answer's method? Help?

Comment: Yes but it's not tracing. :(.  I am sure it's nothing to do with MQTT. It's simple azure sdk client communication with azure portal. so it should be http tracing?

Comment: "not tracing" do you mean there isn't any communication happened on tcp port 8883 or you can't see the packet content you send? For monitoring messages you send to azure iot hub you can also use [device explorer](https://github.com/fsautomata/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/tools/DeviceExplorer/doc/how_to_use_device_explorer.md#monitor) or [iot hub explorer](https://github.com/azure/iothub-explorer).

Comment: From device explorer, it use AMQP protocol, its port is 5671.

Comment: This is the way I created client instance - client = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(IotHubConnectionString, TransportType.Mqtt_WebSocket_Only);    - so will it use 443 port?

Comment: Yes, MQTT over WebSockets use 443 port.

Comment: so how do I filter 443 port in Fiddler or Wire-shark? seems like it's part of header. like "Dst Port: XXXX",  I want to combine IP destination address and port to narrow down the results.

Comment: In wireshark use tcp.port == 443

Comment: I update my answer to add screenshot of wireshark. You can have a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure IoT Hub only supported security communication, for MQTT protocol it use 8883 port number. 
So you need change capture filter to `tcp.port == 8883`.

Ref: [Azure IoT Hub communication protocol and ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-protocols)

Or find the Azure IoT Hub IP address using the following command:

`ping [your-hub-name].azure-devices.net`

Then use this filter:

```
ip.addr == [iothub-address]
```

If you use AMQP, its port is 5671. You can set filter in Wireshark like this:

[image]

Comment: Screenshot helps, but when I send 'single' message it shows many records. Does it mean handshaking happens in many round trips? where I can see this hand shake documents? Basically I want to prove that messages are encrypted on the wire. which line in wireshark proves that message is encrypted? where is the message sit? example: I am sending "hello", where I can see "hello" is encrypted?

Comment: @codetoshare I explained in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/329b8655-5c3f-4518-a45c-36c0116130d9/how-to-troubleshoot-messages-sent-from-local-compter-to-azure-iot-hub-using-wireshark?forum=azureiothub) on MSDN.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. Can u help with encryption question so that I can mark it as answer and close it.

Comment: @codetoshare Hi, after a research I found these links maybe useful for your encryption question: [1](https://packetpushers.net/using-wireshark-to-decode-ssltls-packets/), [2](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/14802/how-to-confirm-encrypted-data-using-wireshark), [3](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/23451/how-can-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-encrypted). Hope it helps. Or you can ask a question on https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/.